# remote inserts are x85 slower then local inserts, why and how to improve?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-insert

:)

I have a 3rd party company that perform about 200-300 inserts per second to our database and there is a huge lag, I am trying to monitor what is causing the lag.

I have PostgreSQL 11 with TimeScaleDb 1.4

so I know that the usual indications can be Disk IO, CPU and Memory.

Cpu, Memory and Disk IO I can easily monitor with top.

top shows cup and memory usage of each process plus it has the `0.0 wa` part that whenever this number increases from zero it means that there are read or write tasks from and to the hard drive that are waiting, which means that Disk IO may be the issue.

while this company is adding rows to our database I monitored and noticed that none of these is an issue! so I decided to make my own stress test script.

the company stated that because I have TimeScaleDB and because I have a lot of indexes on this table, that it delays the rows to be inserted to the database. I thought that they where wrong because if that was an issue I would see a Disk IO load problem.

so I decided to test this myself. I created my own stress test script that generate fake data based on the structure of the table and add rows to it accordingly.

the script is written in GoLang, i'll show the main idea of it here. this is the `goroutine` function that I created for this task:

```
func insertQuery(c <-chan *TestDataRow, d chan bool) {
    for {
        ret := <-c
        if ret == nil {
            log.Printf("broke!")
            d <- true
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(". ")
        _, err = db.NamedExec(`insert into <TABLE>([COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ...])
    values ([:VALUE_1,:VALUE_2,...]);`, *ret)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could insert row to db: %v", err)
        }
    }
}
```

so `*TestDataRow` contains the fields that needs to be inserted to the database. after the main process has finished sending all the row data to the go routine process, it sends a nil as `TestDataRow` to let the go routine know that there will not be any more rows in queue. once the go routine detects the null, it sends `true` through channel `d` to the let the main process know that it finished it's task as well.

and this is the main function of my stress test tool:

```
func main() {
```

I read the config file, connect to the database, and create the fake data to be used

```
    initConfig()
    initPsql(viper.GetString("db.host"), viper.GetString("db.user"), viper.GetString("db.password"), viper.GetString("db.database"), viper.GetString("db.schema"), viper.GetInt("db.port"))
    var rowsCount int64 = 10000
    InitDummyData(rowsCount)
```

I parse the `-time` and `-count` flags and calculate how may microseconds delay should be used when I insert each line to the database

```
    log.Printf("pg-cdr-stress-my-ass-off v%v\n", VERSION)
    pTime := flag.String("time", "", "[required] to run this test for how long ? (example - 10s, 1m5s, 2h, 1d2h)")
    pCount := flag.String("count", "", "[required] how many times ? (10000,10KB,2MB)")
    pHelp := flag.Bool("help", false, "show usage")
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("help flag: %v", *pHelp)
    if *pHelp {
        flag.PrintDefaults()
    } else if len(*pTime) == 0 || len(*pCount) == 0 {
        log.Println("please provide all required parameters")
        log.Println("usage:")
        flag.PrintDefaults()
    } else {
        log.Printf("received parameters: time: %v count: %v\n", *pTime, *pCount)
        d, err := time.ParseDuration(*pTime)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not parse time: %v", err)
        }
        milliSeconds := d.Milliseconds()
        microSeconds := d.Microseconds()
        var count int
        if parsedCount, err := strconv.Atoi(*pCount); err == nil {
            count = parsedCount
        } else {

            n, err := bytesize.Parse(*pCount)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("could not parse count: %v", err)
            }
            count, err = strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSuffix(n.Format("%.0f", "bytes", false), "B"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("could not parse count parameter property: %v", err)
            }
        }
        log.Printf("will run %v times at %v milliseconds", count, milliSeconds)
        executeEveryMicroSeconds := microSeconds / int64(count)
        log.Printf("will execute every %v microSeconds", executeEveryMicroSeconds)
        milDuration := time.Microsecond * time.Duration(executeEveryMicroSeconds)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not parse duration: %v", err)
        }
```

I created channel `c` with a 100000 queue to send the TestDataRow and channel `closeC` to get back from the go routine when all the rows where inserted to the database and I execute the `insertQuery` go routine

```
        currentCount := 0
        c := make(chan *TestDataRow, 100000)
        closeC := make(chan bool)
        go insertQuery(c, closeC)
```

I start a for loop for a range delay of the microseconds needed to wait before each insert will be added , inside of it I create a dummy row, send it to the go routine, increment `currentCount` and break the loop if I added the required amount of rows

```
        currentNano := time.Now()
        for range time.Tick(milDuration) {
            c <- GenerateDummyRow()
            currentCount++
            fmt.Printf("%v ", currentCount)
            if currentCount >= count {
                break
            }
        }
        log.Println("done looping, waiting for child..")
```

then I'm sending `nil` to the child go routine to let it know that there are no more rows to be added and waiting for output from `closeC` to know when the child go routine has finished it's task and then I print the amount of time this task took

```
        c <- nil
        <-closeC
        log.Println("child is done!")
        elpased := time.Since(currentNano)
        log.Printf("task finished in %v seconds", float64(elpased.Milliseconds())/1000)
    }
}
```

I have no problem with this code.. I'm not looking to improve it since it's just for this test, just showing you what I'm doing so you can see the all picture.

ok now I'm running this app with parameters of `-count 500 -time 1s` so it will add 500 rows in 1 second range which means 2000 microseconds delay between each insert.

just one more info.. I print the number of the line when it's sent to the go-routine and I print a dot `.` when a row is inserted to the database. to make sure that the main app is not waiting for the go routine to finish adding the line before it sending more data.

so if I execute this task remotely, which means I run this script locally while connecting to my remote ubuntu server with postgresql, I get the following output:

```
2019/11/28 15:48:55 will run 500 times at 1000 milliseconds
2019/11/28 15:48:55 will execute every 2000 microSeconds
1 . 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 . 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 . 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 . 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 . 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 . 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 2019/11/28 15:48:56 done looping, waiting for child..
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 2019/11/28 15:50:20 broke!
2019/11/28 15:50:20 child is done!
2019/11/28 15:50:20 task finished in 85.309 seconds
```

running this script on the remote server, which means it will connect to the database locally and running same script with same parameters

```
019/11/28 13:58:49 will execute every 2000 microSeconds
1 . 2 3 4 . . 5 . 6 . 7 . 8 . 9 . 10 . . 11 . 12 . 13 . 14 . 15 . 16 . 17 . 18 . 19 . 20 . 21 . 22 . 23 . 24 . 25 . 26 . 27 . 28 . 29 . 30 . 31 . 32 . 33 . 34 . 35 . 36 . 37 . 38 . 39 . 40 41 42 . 43 . 44 . 45 . . 46 . 47 . 48 . 49 . 50 . 51 . . 52 . 53 . 54 . 55 . 56 . 57 . 58 . 59 . 60 . 61 . 62 . 63 . 64 . 65 . 66 . 67 . 68 . 69 . 70 . 71 . 72 . 73 . 74 . 75 . 76 . 77 . 78 . 79 . 80 . 81 . 82 . 83 . 84 . 85 . 86 . 87 . 88 . 89 . 90 . 91 . 92 . 93 . 94 . 95 . 96 . 97 . 98 . 99 . 100 . 101 . 102 . 103 . 104 . 105 . 106 . 107 . 108 . 109 . 110 . 111 . 112 . 113 . 114 . 115 . 116 . 117 . 118 . 119 . 120 . 121 . 122 . 123 . 124 . 125 . 126 . 127 . 128 . 
129 . 130 . 131 . 132 . 133 . 134 . 135 . 136 . 137 . 138 . 139 . 140 . 141 . 142 . 143 . 144 . 145 . 146 . 147 . 148 . 149 . 150 . 151 . 152 . 153 . 154 . 155 . 156 . 157 . 158 . 159 . 160 . 161 . 162 . 163 . 164 . 165 . 166 . 167 . 168 . 169 . 170 . 171 . 172 . 173 . 174 . 175 . 176 . 177 . 178 . 179 . 180 . 181 . 182 . 183 . 
184 . 185 . 186 . 187 . 188 . 189 . 190 . 191 . 192 . 193 . 194 . 195 . 196 . 197 . 198 . 199 . 200 . 201 . 202 . 203 . 204 . 205 . 206 . 207 . 208 . 209 . 210 . 211 . 212 . 213 . 214 . 215 . 216 . 217 . 218 . 219 . 220 . 221 . 222 . 223 . 224 . 225 . 226 . 227 . 228 . 229 . 230 . 231 . 232 . 233 . 234 . 235 . 236 . 237 . 238 . 
239 . 240 . 241 . 242 . 243 . 244 . 245 . 246 . 247 . 248 . 249 . 250 . 251 . 252 . 253 . 254 . 255 . 256 . 257 . 258 . 259 . 260 . 261 . 262 . 263 . 264 . 265 . 266 . 267 . 268 . 269 . 270 . 271 . 272 . 273 . 274 . 275 . 276 . 277 . 278 . 279 . 280 . 281 . 282 . 283 . 284 . 285 . 286 . 287 . 288 . 289 . 290 . 291 . 292 . 293 . 
294 . 295 . 296 . 297 . 298 . 299 . 300 . 301 . 302 . 303 . 304 . 305 . 306 . 307 . 308 . 309 . 310 . 311 . 312 . 313 . 314 . 315 . 316 . 317 . 318 . 319 . 320 . 321 . 322 . 323 . 324 . 325 . 326 . 327 . 328 . 329 . 330 . 331 . 332 . 333 . 334 . 335 . 336 . 337 . 338 . 339 . 340 . 341 . 342 . 343 . 344 . 345 . 346 . 347 . 348 . 
349 . 350 . 351 . 352 . 353 . 354 . 355 . 356 . 357 . 358 . 359 . 360 . 361 . 362 . 363 . 364 . 365 . 366 . 367 . 368 . 369 . 370 . 371 . 372 . 373 . 374 . 375 . 376 . 377 . 378 . 379 . 380 . 381 . 382 . 383 . 384 . 385 . 386 . 387 . 388 . 389 . 390 . 391 . 392 . 393 . 394 . 395 . 396 . 397 . 398 . 399 . 400 . 401 . 402 . 403 . 
404 . 405 . 406 . 407 . 408 . 409 . 410 . 411 . 412 . 413 . 414 . 415 . 416 . 417 . 418 . 419 . 420 . 421 . 422 . 423 . 424 . 425 . 426 . 427 . 428 . 429 . 430 . 431 . 432 . 433 . 434 . 435 . 436 . 437 . 438 . 439 . 440 . 441 . 442 . 443 . 444 . 445 . 446 . 447 . 448 . 449 . 450 . 451 . 452 . 453 . 454 . 455 . 456 . 457 . 458 . 
459 . 460 . 461 . 462 . 463 . 464 . 465 . 466 . 467 . 468 . 469 . 470 . 471 . 472 . 473 . 474 . 475 . 476 . 477 . 478 . 479 . 480 . 481 . 482 . 483 . 484 . 485 . 486 . 487 . 488 . 489 . 490 . 491 . 492 . 493 . 494 . 495 . 496 . 497 . 498 . 499 . 500 2019/11/28 13:58:50 done looping, waiting for child..
. 2019/11/28 13:58:50 broke!
2019/11/28 13:58:50 child is done!
2019/11/28 13:58:50 task finished in 1.001 seconds
```

as you can see here inserting the rows remotely is... 85 times slower?!? why is that?

I though maybe it's related to the network speed

and I google and show the article at https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5799/test-network-speed-without-wasting-disk on how to check network speed. so I executed it and go the following:

```
4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 17.8028 s, 241 MB/s
```

so the network is not an issue.

what am I missing ?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - yeah.. that was exactly it. i didn't know that network latency can affect this much. doing bulk inserts resolves it. didn't know that network latency can have this much effect on performance. I was just wondering if there is some sort or configuration or anything from my side that I can do to improve latency or I should just move to bulk inserts and leave configuration as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak Go, but if it is lots of little statements via network vs. lots of little statements locally, then the problem is the network latency (not the bandwidth).

You should use multi-line inserts

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...)
```

or [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).